# A question on conditional expectation involving another conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation

$X$, $Y$, $Z$ are 3 random variables.

Let $g(\cdot)$ denote a conditional expectation such that $g(X,Z)=E(Y|X,Z)$

Need to show $E(Y|X, g(X,Z))$. I think $E(Y|X, g(X,Z))=E(Y|X,Z)$ and my rationale is given below:

\begin{align}
E(Y|X, g(X,Z))&=E(E(Y|X,g(X,Z),Z)|X,g(X,Z)) \\
              &=E(E(Y|X,Z)|X,g(X,Z)) \qquad \because X \, \text{and} \, Z \, \text{determine} \, g(X,Z) \\
&=E(g(X,Z)|X,g(X,Z)) \\
&=g(X,Z)=E(Y|X,Z)
\end{align}

Any issue with my rationale? thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right. Since I am more comfortable using a notation with $\sigma$-algebras let's introduce
$$
{\cal A}:=\sigma\Big(X,g(X,Z)\Big)\,,\quad {\cal B}:=\sigma(X,Z)
$$
which clearly satisfy ${\cal A}\subseteq {\cal B}$ so that we can use the tower property:

\begin{align}\tag{1}
E[\,Y\,|\,{\cal A}\,]=E\Big[\,E[\,Y\,|\,{\cal B}\,]\,\Big|\,{\cal A}\,\Big]\,.
\end{align}
By the Doob-Dynkin factorization lemma: $E[\,Y\,|\,{\cal B}\,]=g(X,Z)$ so that the RHS of (1) becomes
$$
E\Big[\,g(X,Z)\,\Big|\,{\cal A}\,\Big]=g(X,Z).
$$
This holds because $g(X,Z)$ is trivially ${\cal A}$-measurable.
In other words, we have shown that
$$\tag{2}
\boxed{E[\,Y\,|\,{\cal A}\,]=g(X,Z)\,.}
$$